# Is it possible to override the way play.api.libs.json write options?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I work with Play! scala 2.4 and I have several simple case class like this one:

```
case class A(a: Option[String])
```

I would like to override the way Json.toJson(A) works when the option is empty.

Here is what I have done:

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = Json.writes[A]

implicit def ow[T](implicit w: Writes[T]): Writes[Option[T]] = Writes {
  case None => JsString("[]")
  case Some(t) => Json.toJson(t)
}

Json.toJson(A(a = None)) mustBe Json.parse("""{"a":"[]"}""")
```

but it still parses the class as usual (i.e. `{}` instead of `{"a":"[]"}` as I would like).
What can I do in order to make this test pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible using the `Json.writes` macro, because it is written to specially handle `Option` to use `readNullable[B]`. This means you will need to need to use combinators to define `Writes[A]`. Unfortunately, defining `Writes` for an object with only one field is a little more cumbersome than one that has more.

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = Writes(a => Json.obj("a" -> a.a))

scala> Json.toJson(A(None))
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"a":"[]"}
```

Example with multiple fields:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class A(a: Option[String], b: Int)

implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = (
    (__ \ "a").write[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "b").write[Int]
)(unlift(A.unapply))

scala> Json.toJson(A(None, 10))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"a":"[]","b":10}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know this way to do it but in my application the case classes contain a lot more fields and I have a lot of case classes (sorry my question was unclear). That's why I'm looking for a generic way in order to not rewrite every writers... Can you please explain me why it is less cumbersome for an object with more fields?

Comment: @Simon I updated my answer with an example. If your `Writes` for these case classes are currently using `Json.writes[A]`, re-writing them is unavoidable.

Comment: Here's the relevant part of the macro that uses `writeNullable`, which will ignore `Writes[Option[A]]` and do its own thing: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/ec9de32196ae967619251cf6d61442fb27c88fe0/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L176-L179

Comment: Ok, it's a pity... Do you maybe know an other library that allows to write custom json writers for case classes with options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `aWrites` with the one below to add `"a":` part:

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = new Writes[A] {
  override def writes(o: A): JsValue =
    Json.obj("a" -> Json.toJson(o.a))
}
```

EDIT: Using `apply` method of `Writes` object is clearer and a better practice for Scala, so I suggest you to use @m-z's answer.

Comment: As I told to m-e, I'm looking for a generic solution, sorry that my question was not clear about that.